# What variety of Goumi berry will thrive under an apple tree in USDA zone 4a?

Tags: shrubs, variety-selection, soft-fruit

I want to plant a [goumi berry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaeagnus_multiflora) bush underneath an apple tree.  My goal is to have as much fruit as I can. I am in Minnesota, USDA zone 4a.

What variety should I order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goumi bushes can be a bit tricky to buy. There are only a handful of nurseries in the US that sell them, most of those do not sell named varieties, and some of them are even selling other Elaeagnus species mislabled as goumi berries. The only two named varieties I've seen are called Sweet Scarlet and Red Gem. Anecdotally, I've heard Sweet Scarlet tastes better. Personally, I have an unnamed variety from Raintree nursery (I hope it is OK to list the nursery - I am not affiliated in any way, except as a happy customer), and the flavor is good.